# Sinatra error: "Gem::LoadError: Unable to activate actionpack-3.2.3, because activesupport-3.2.8 conflicts with activesupport (= 3.2.3) "

Tags: ruby, rubygems, sinatra, delimiter, actionpack

I would like to comma delimit large numbers in my Sinatra app, so I did some Googling and found that I can do so by adding the following:

```
require 'action_view/helpers/number_helper'
```

Then, it seems I am supposed to be able to do things like:

```
number_with_delimiter(12345678, :delimiter => ',')
```

However, I get the following error:

```
Gem::LoadError: Unable to activate actionpack-3.2.3, because activesupport-3.2.8 conflicts with activesupport (= 3.2.3)
```

I'm not sure how to fix this.

Comment: when you pasted the error, was so hard to read its message? :) why wont you consider to uninstall activesupport (= 3.2.3)

Comment: @slivu i read the message but was unsure on how to do what you are suggesting

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a Gemfile and bundler with your app. There you can explicitly set the versions of each gem. See http://gembundler.com for more information on how to do so.